# IIS Redirects preserve path

Tags: redirect, iis, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to achieve the following via IIS:

1. Redirect requests for App-A to Server-A
2. Redirect requests for App-B to Server-B
3. Redirect everything else to Server-C

I have 1 & 2 working via simple redirect rules:

1.

Requested URL: Matches the pattern

Pattern: ^App-A

Action type: Redirect

Redirect URL: https://Server-A.fqdn/App-A

2.

Requested URL: Matches the pattern

Pattern: ^App-B

Action type: Redirect

Redirect URL: https://Server-B.fqdn/App-B

3.

I haven't sorted this one out yet.

The following is not working:

Requested URL: Does **not** match the pattern

Pattern: ^App-A, ^App-B

Action type: Redirect

Redirect URL: https://Server-C.fqdn/

Seems that the requested path is not preserved and appended to the redirect URL therefore the destination is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

3.

Requested URL: Matches the pattern

Pattern: **^(.*)**

Action type: Redirect

Redirect URL: https://Server-C.fqdn/**{R:0}**

Since rules are processed in order, rule 3 is successfully processed for everything else **^(.*)** when the request does not match rule 1 (/App-A) or rule 2 (/App-B). **{R:0}** preserves the path.